# Variable may be uninitialised warning when it should not be possible Java

Tags: java, java-11, java-threads

I am finishing a thread which handles registration to a messenger app where to circumvent concurrency issues with the database I have loaded a full hashSet of usernames to the thread which is updated dynamically within and without the thread having passed it around by reference. My problem is that I add the username to the set near the beginning to prevent other registerThread instances seeing it as available as they must be unique in this system. I want to be able to retain the username I get from the object read from the first readObject method call so that I can remove it from the Set should any exception occur from within the inner try catch block. what might be the best way to do this?

```
public class RequestHandlerThread implements Runnable {

private SSLSocket sslSocket;
private HashMap<Integer, ConcurrentMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>>> networkMap;
private Set<String> usernames;
private int authIterations;
private DatabaseUtilities databaseUtilities;
private Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{1,255}");
private Pattern passPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w");
private static int nextRequestId = 1000000;

public RequestHandlerThread(SSLSocket sslSocket, HashMap<Integer, ConcurrentMap<Integer,
        Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>>> networkMap, Set<String> usernames, int authIterations) throws SQLException {
    this.sslSocket = sslSocket;
    this.networkMap = networkMap;
    this.usernames = usernames;
    this.authIterations = authIterations;
    databaseUtilities = DatabaseUtilities.getInstance();
}

public void run() {


    try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
         ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream()))) {

        try {
            RequestJoinPacket requestJoinPacket;
            // RECEIVE DATA FROM THE CLIENT
            requestJoinPacket = (RequestJoinPacket) input.readObject();

            // VALIDATE THE DATA ELSE RESPOND FAIL

            ConcurrentMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap;
            BlockingQueue<Packet> sendChannel, receiveChannel;
            int requestId;
            // HAD TO ADD PLACEHOLDER VALUE BECAUSE COMPILER MUH DUMB
            Packet result = new Packet();
            boolean cont = true;


            if (namePattern.matcher(requestJoinPacket.getAlias()).matches() &&
                    namePattern.matcher(requestJoinPacket.getUsername()).matches() &&
                    passPattern.matcher(requestJoinPacket.getPassword()).matches() &&
                    networkMap.containsKey(requestJoinPacket.getNid()) &&
                    (channelMap = networkMap.get(requestJoinPacket.getNid())).containsKey(requestJoinPacket.getCid()) &&
                    channelMap.get(requestJoinPacket.getCid()).isPresent() &&
                    usernames.add(requestJoinPacket.getUsername())) {

                sendChannel = channelMap.get(requestJoinPacket.getCid()).get();
                // !!! MAKE configurable
                receiveChannel = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
                requestId = getNextRequestId();


            } else {
                usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
                throw new FailedJoinException("nid / cid invalid or user inactive");
            }

            // ADD THIS THREAD TO THE REQUESTED NETWORKCHANNEL AND MAKE REQUEST OF USER

            requestJoinPacket = new RequestJoinPacket(requestJoinPacket.getCid(), requestId, requestJoinPacket.getAlias());
            channelMap.put(requestId, Optional.of(receiveChannel));
            if(!sendChannel.offer(requestJoinPacket)) {
                usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
                throw new FailedJoinException("user inactive or busy");
            }
            // IF USER DID NOT EXIST RESPOND FAIL / IF THEY DECLINE RESPOND FAIL
            // spawn off two sub threads, one waits for receiveChannel response and
            // the other waits for a cancel from the user, first to ring bell wins

            CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            Callable<Packet> waitForResponse = () -> {
               Packet packet = receiveChannel.take();
               countDownLatch.countDown();
               return packet;
            };

            // ??? PROBLEM WITH POTENTIAL FOR USER TO LOG OFF BETWEEN THIS TIME
            Callable<Packet> waitForCancel = () -> {
                CancelOperationPacket packet = (CancelOperationPacket) input.readObject();
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                return packet;
            };

            // interrupt on countdown

            FutureTask<Packet> response = new FutureTask<>(waitForResponse);
            FutureTask<Packet> cancel = new FutureTask<>(waitForCancel);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(response);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(cancel);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            // Interrupt in case any are still running
            if(countDownLatch.getCount() == 1) {
                t1.interrupt();
                t2.interrupt();
                usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
                throw new FailedJoinException("Timed out");
            }

            while(cont) {
                if(response.isDone()){
                    result = response.get();
                    cont = false;
                    t2.interrupt();
                } else if(cancel.isDone()){
                    t1.interrupt();
                    usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
                    throw new FailedJoinException("operation canceled");
                }
            }
            // ON ACCEPT THEN ADD THEN CREATE HASH FOR PASSWORD AND ADD TO DATABASE


            if(result.getType() == Type.REFUSE_JOIN) {
                usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
                throw new FailedJoinException("join refused by chosen user");
            }else if(result.getType() == Type.ACCEPT_JOIN){
                SecurityUtilities.getAuthenticationHash(requestJoinPacket.getPassword(), authIterations);
//                    databaseUtilities.addUser()
            }


            // ADD THE NEW USER CID TO THE CORRECT CHANNELMAP WITH AN EMPTY OPTIONAL


            // RESPOND JOIN SUCCESSFUL

        }catch (IOException | FailedJoinException | IllegalStateException |
                InterruptedException | ExecutionException | ClassNotFoundException | GeneralSecurityException e){
           // REALLY ANNOYING I CANT REMOVE USERNAME HERE AS ANY FAILURE MAY LEAVE IT IN
            output.writeObject(new RefuseJoinPacket());}
    } catch (IOException e) {}

}

private static synchronized int getNextRequestId(){
    return nextRequestId++;
}
}
```

As is visible from the code I have written the line:

```
usernames.remove(requestJoinPacket.getUsername());
```

prior to throwing every exception but I am aware this will not fire for the other checked exceptions which is wrong. Thanks

Comment: In this case, in contrast to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62612847/2711488), the compiler is absolutely right. The first `requestJoinPacket = (RequestJoinPacket) input.readObject();` can already fail with an `IOException` or `ClassNotFoundException` (and even the `IllegalStateException` can not precluded), so a `catch` clause for these exception types can not access the `requestJoinPacket` variable that would not be initialized in this case. Besides that, you’re reinventing `ExecutorService.invokeAny​(…)`

Comment: Ahh thanks I thought it could only fail with a ClassNotFoundException, I have moved it into the outer try catch and all is well now. Thanks for that I was unaware of its existence.